# Difference between using StreamReader.ReadLine and StreamReaderEnumerable

Tags: c#

Is there any difference between these two codes?

```
1.     
  using (StreamReader sr = New StreamReader("filePath"))
  {       
      while ((string line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
          DoSomeThing();
      }
  }


2.  
   foreach (string line in new StreamReaderEnumerable("filePath"))
   {
       if (line != null)
       {
           DoSomeThing();
       }
   }
```

Is there any performance concern when using one over the other, or they are functional identical during runtime?

Comment: `both return IEnumerable<string>` No...they don't...

Comment: The check should be just line != null - otherwise empty line will end reading the stream.

Comment: Also the string is not IDisposable - can you rewrite the code snippet so it can be compiled ?

Comment: I don't think StreamReaderEnumerable() is a Net Library method.  so one case you are using a Net Library method (StreamReader) and the other case you are not.

Comment: So, what exactly is `StreamReaderEnumerable`?

Comment: @Gasper it's an example class from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The code style has no effect on the fundamental cost of having to read from a file.

Comment: Note that the second code block will loop infinitely, as you never change the value of `line` within the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition for [`SteamReaderEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx), `StreamReader.ReadLine()` is used.  I noticed your custom solution solution uses the same method.  As a result, I recommend using option 1 since you are not using LINQ to work with the lines.  This way you can avoid the extra overhead of the `SteamReaderEnumerable` class.

If you did need to use LINQ to access the lines, the `SteamReaderEnumerable` class would provide a simple and robust way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference between these two codes?

Yes - one works; one doesn't.  Your second code block will loop endlessly since you never change the value of `line` in your while loop.  The *actual* equivalent would be:

```
foreach (string line in new StreamReaderEnumerable("filePath"))
{
    DoSomeThing();
}
```

Looking at the example code, the only difference is the overhead of an enumerator object, which should be negligible.

Comment: Thanks @D Stanley, edited xD